# ImportError: No module named 'django' despite having it installed running apache2 server

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache

I know that many have posted similar question however I tried most solution without success.
I'm trying to host a webpage with apache2 and django in python3.

In the error log I found `ImportError: No module named 'django'` when accessing the `wsgi.py`file, where I also added `import sys`, `sys.version` to confirm which python version is used and from the error log I can see that I'm running following python version `3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]`.

When I run `python3.5` I see that I uses the same python version and here I can run `import django` without any error!

EDIT: I checked `django.__file__`and saw that it was located in `/home/USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/init.py` and that path `/home/USERNAME/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages` wasn't in the `sys.path` that tried to run django. But adding it with `sys.path.append(path)` didn't help :(

Any thoughts what I might have messed up?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Setup the whole configuration in VirtualEnv then , i suggest you to activate it by,

```
source /location to /env/bin activate
pip3 install django=version_id
```

or `pip install django=version id` 
if you want to pass  version id then its good or it will install the latest django from your repo.
Now test Django Version there.
Hope you will no get the error.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that I have created anything in a VirtualEnv (or at least not on purpose)

What do you mean with source /location? and version_id?

Comment: It means you are going to install django globally on your os,  its not a better idea,  but if you want then, leave the first one, "source bin/activate" and run the one of command, to install django.

Answer (score 0):

Location - means the path where env will be located in project directory, if you have followed the standard installation process of django or else you don't need, and version id- vesion of django framework.

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood how to solve it! first I had to run `pip3 uninstall django` then run `sudo pip3 install django`.